# LAN connection in school

Tags: network-access

Hi I currently working in school where  we don't have LAN connection only one pc is connected to WiFi.
Now I want to make a LAN Connection of 6 pc.
Plz give me some guidance and which architecture is best for 6 pc's @ school level.
Thanx in advance.

Comment: Are the PCs close enough to all use WiFi?  If not there are many small Ethernet switches that would work for you.  Unfortunately, we can't recommend any specific products.

Answer (score 1):

Get a Switch and share the internet connection of the PC connected to the WIFI to all the other PCs accross the switch. This can be done on a simple way. Post if you can get a switch and here we can help you.

Comment: I already try this method but internet speed at other pc's is too slow

Comment: Sorry buddy, but, if the internet connection of the PC connected to WIFI is, eg, 54 MBps, with that method your will share this between the 7 PCs, aprox 8 MBps is what you get. Another idea is find the way to connect the 6 PCs to WIFI, but, for that, you need to have on all the PC Wireless Network Adapters.

Answer (score 1):

Is this is a school that doesn't have an infrastructure, you really want to start building the infrastructure properly as there will be a future demand for more connections/bandwidth/file servers/wireless/etc. I have walked in many a school where parents and other unqualified helpers created standardless spaghetti networks so as to cut down costs but later cost more $$$ to fix.

Search the web for structured cabling (blackbox.com had a good pdf), physical/logical infrastructure and post more of your questions for this community to assist you after you've researched your solutions. It's not that often nowadays that someone has the opportunity to start a school in the right way towards IT :-)

Hint: Lookup a star topology, it's the easiest to troubleshoot and scale up from.

Answer (score 0):

Connect all 6 of the pc's to the wifi ap.

Going the wifi route is the most cost effective and quickest to deploy.

Look for a AP that has 2.4GHz and 5GHz radios so you have more bandwidth, and connect the Server/Internet to the Ethernet ports on the AP, to reduce the wifi hop for most traffic to one.

If you have to place some pc's more that 20 meters from the AP or there is a lot of walls reducing the signal think about adding more AP's connected with ethernet Cat5/Cat6 cabling to central AP, avoid wifi bridge links between AP's as it halves the bandwidth.  use the same ssid en wpa2 key, selecting not overlapping channels for each AP.